# cp: Copy multiple files to multiple destinations from index

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, sed

I have a directory containing multiple configuration files that I'd like to copy to disparate parts of my home directory. In order to give more control over where the files go and which are copied, I have an index file (`CONFIGSINDEX`) of tab separated files and destinations; the file names on the left, and the destinations on the right, like so:

```
#files	destinations
zshrc	$HOME/.zshrc
i3config	$HOME/.config/i3/config
mu4e.el	$HOME/.emacs.d/mu4e.el
xinitrc	$HOME/.xinitrc
# and so on
```

In order to copy the files to their destinations I ran the following:

```
cp -v $(sed "s/\s*#.*//g; /^$/ d" CONFIGSINDEX | awk {'print $1'}) $(sed "s/\s*#.*//g; /^$/ d" CONFIGSINDEX | awk {'print $2'})
```

and received to following error:

```
cp: target '$HOME/.xinitrc' is not a directory
```

This happens regaurdless of what I have on the last line, and I have previously copied individual files like this (eg, `cp xinitrc ~/.xinitrc`) without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cp` is just one command. Two `sed`s will independently generate many arguments for it. There are few problems with this:

1. It's still *one* command, not one command per line of `CONFIGSINDEX`. The code in the [first revision of your question](https://superuser.com/revisions/1469318/1) tried to iterate over lines; this was a cumbersome attempt (reading the same file again and again is weak) but it might kinda succeed in running `cp` once per line. In your current code only the last object is treated as a target. Almost all objects you meant to be targets are considered source. In addition, because there are multiple sources specified, the last argument is expected to be a (target) *directory*, not a file.
2. Even if you managed to run one `cp` per line, retrieving objects from `sed` with command substitution (`$(…)`) is still hardly useful here because:

   - in general you need proper quoting to handle names with spaces etc.;
   - the shell performs command substitution after parameter and variable expansion; variable expansion is not performed again, so `$HOME` stays literal; the message `target '$HOME/.xinitrc' is not a directory` refers to the *literal* path `$HOME/.xinitrc` (to be clear: with *literal* `$`) which obviously doesn't exist as a directory.

---

To deal with `$HOME` in your file, you need to make the shell parse it, so variable expansion actually happens. I guess this can be done with `sed` and `eval`. The purpose of `eval` is to parse some string again.

But note your file is almost a shell script. If you added `cp -v` at the beginning of every relevant line, it would be a script you could run with `sh` or `bash`. So let's do this. This will only *print* the dynamically created script:

```
<CONFIGSINDEX sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e '/^$/d' -e '/^#/d' -e 's/^/cp -v -- /'
```

Check if it looks like commands you would want to type in your shell. If it does, pipe the whole command to `sh`, it will be like this:

```
<CONFIGSINDEX sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e '/^$/d' -e '/^#/d' -e 's/^/cp -v -- /' | sh
```

A bit of explanation. `sed` does four things:

- it removes [space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15767954/10765659) from the beginning of each line;
- it removes empty lines (and because of the above this includes lines that used to consist of space characters only);
- it removes lines starting with `#` (this includes lines that used to start with space character(s) and then `#`);
- it adds `cp -v --` and one space character at the very beginning of the line.

Finally the resulting script is passed to a separate shell (`sh`). Tabs in your file will separate arguments just fine.

There are pros and cons of interpreting the file like this (or with `eval`). The main advantage is you can use all pieces of the syntax the shell supports. This includes parameters (variables), like in your case. But also quoting or escaping special characters, e.g. this line will be parsed fine:

```
'name with spaces'	"$HOME/new	name	with	tabs"
```

The main disadvantage is *you can use all pieces of the syntax the shell supports*. Without paying attention you may use them inadvertently or somebody will deliberately use the file to *inject code*. Examples:

```
foo	new_name; rm -rf very_important_dir
```

In practice it's impossible to sanitize lines before passing them to `sh` (or using `eval`). The solution I presented is quite straightforward and elegant in a way, but use it only if the file is under your total control.

The solution will not fit if another tool uses (or generates) the file and therefore you can neither quote nor escape. I mean if you cannot do this:

```
'name with spaces'	'foo/name with spaces'
# or
name\ with\ spaces	foo/name\ with\ spaces
```

only this:

```
name with spaces	foo/name with spaces
```

then passing to `sh` won't work and you need another approach.

---

Another approach may be like this:

```
<CONFIGSINDEX sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e '/^$/d' -e '/^#/d' -e 's:$HOME:'"$HOME"':g' \
| while IFS=$'\t' read -r source target garbage; do
  cp -v -- "$source" "$target"
done
```

(In case you're not familiar with `\` at the very end of the line: it makes the line continue, so here the command is like `sed … | while read …`).

Now `sed` is responsible not only for removing empty lines and comments; it also replaces `$HOME` with the actual content of `$HOME` returned by the shell. `read` reads two tab-separated strings (excessive fields, if any, are assigned to `garbage` which is never used). This is quite safe, now you cannot inject code at all, no arbitrary code can be executed.

There are disadvantages though:

- If `$HOME` is in the file and the variable contains the tab character (in theory it may), it will break the logic. This can be fixed by "expanding" `$HOME` after `read`, separately for `$source` (if needed) and `$target`.
- If `$HOME` was in the file and the variable contained `:`, it would break the `sed` command. But because of the syntax of `/etc/passwd` (where `:` is a separator) `$HOME` will probably never contain `:`. This is the very reason I used `:` in `sed` here.
- `$HOMERSIMPSON` will be altered but not `${HOME}`.
- To expand other variables you need more `sed` code.

Therefore you may want yet another approach.

---

Yet another approach is with `envsubst`. It substitutes variables from its environment. Note this means it won't see all shell variables, only exported ones. `HOME` is in the environment for sure, so `envsubst` will work with it. The tool is not required by POSIX so you may not have it. If you do have it, this is the way to go:

```
<CONFIGSINDEX sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e '/^$/d' -e '/^#/d' | envsubst \
| while IFS=$'\t' read -r source target garbage; do
  cp -v -- "$source" "$target"
done
```

Now `sed` doesn't handle `$HOME`, `envsubst` does. The tool will handle `$HOME` and `${HOME}`. It will handle other environment variables as well, unless you restrict it (e.g. `envsubst '$HOME'`).

As far as I can tell this code is very safe and robust.